# How to create literal object from array united to an object in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I've stopped by upon the following code snippet in Typescript:

```
type SortedList = T[] & {_brand: "sorted" };

function binarySearch<T>(xs: SortedList<T>, x: T): boolean 
      let low = 0;
      let high = xs.length - 1;

      while (high >= low) {
          const mid = low + Math.floor((high - low) / 2);
          const v = xs[mid];
          if (v === x) {
              return true;
          }
          [low, high] = x > v ? [mid + 1, high] : [low, mid - 1];
      }
  return false;
}
```

I am wondering how I could create a literal object of type SortedList?

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
const sortedList: SortedList<string> = Object.assign(["test"], { _brand: "sorted" } as const)
```

If you don't want the performance penalty incurred by `Object.assign` you can also make a utility method which does typecasting:

```
function sorted<T>(_arr: T[]) {
    const arr = _arr as SortedList<T>
    arr._brand = "sorted"
    return arr
}
const sortedList: SortedList<string> = sorted(["test"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Rubydesic's answer with Object.assign, it's likely intended to be used something like this:

```
// never manually create a `SortedList` - only create using this function
function sortList<T>(list: T[], sortFn?: (a: T, b: T) => number): SortedList<T> {
  return Object.assign([...list].sort(sortFn), { _brand: "sorted" } as const);
}

const list = [3, 4, 1, 5, 7];
const sorted = sortList(list);

// this ensures type safety against potential problems like this
// (attempting to binary search an unsorted list)
binarySearch(list, 3); // Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SortedList<number>'.

// ...while still allowing this
binarySearch(sorted, 3); // OK
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gJ2BAJgGQJYGdgB4AqAfFALxT4DaAulAGRQDeA+gEYICGAdigFxQBEWRMhT8oAXwDcAKGkAzAK6cAxsAxxOUFhk7sEIGBD3KAFgUIAKAB5Y+8JKkw5zAGihW++AJR8WcOAA2RpoM0lDhEUHAUAFwAO6kUAAMMhGRENEmGADmJok2AHRBnNnAeQC0UACMMmFpUHFZQVAWWblQhGSxcV6MdfURyho4UAC2GCiJ3VAA1FAAsuxlBXKxiBatORUx8b0A9FAATF6pA4PD0QBu+VgU4yhUp2dQGHIt1ySf7r2hzwMIGQUCE0wAQCggTzO4n6Zwo3TcbRMNDIVg6UGuAH4oHcJrNqgitjQ+HD4m57lBKlVHjDwtDwgDgEDNHJ2AEsBDpND5EpVOpNEIkE48EQLAFsMBPNQ3ALgAAxTgYvgWdieNwsTy9EjETgKUYsCAIHywYSOcXmPr0wHAqAAeRYACsIKoCuwsFgcpwLBQCj6xTgqAUZRYZfKvG4GFBWBxuHxBCbRBIoK6oENODgTpzZKmRn7omQKABmNwAFjcVTcAFY3AB2anZ6Iy1CJGVC0XijPSbS6fSGYwmNs4NwFjNdvQGIwIUzB+NDjNAA)